# Phanteon FTP connection not create file and folder

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files

connettendomi via FTP to a remote server using Pantheon files, clicking the right button I display the "New" to create files and folders.

Is there any way to solve?

Thank you

Comment: It works with SFTP (SSH) but not FTP at the moment.  I have created a bug about this and will look into it.

Comment: Can you link the bug link please?